# How to set file name without extension in camel Header using Java DSL?

Tags: apache-camel

I need to set the file name without extension in header. While searching I got the below blueprint/spring code snippet. I want to achieve the same through Java DSL. can any one help me?

```
<camel:route>
<camel:from uri="file://input/orders" />
<camel:setHeader headerName="FileNameWithoutExtension">
    <camel:simple>${file:onlyname.noext}</camel:simple>
</camel:setHeader>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out. We have to follow the below syntax

```
.setHeader("FileNameWithoutExtension",simple("${file:onlyname.noext}"))
```